# How to get string from command in windows

Tags: bash, window

in this command `flutter --version --machine`. I have this output

```
{
  "frameworkVersion": "3.7.1",
  "channel": "unknown",
  "repositoryUrl": "unknown source",
  "frameworkRevision": "7048ed95a5ad3e43d697e0c397464193991fc230",
  "frameworkCommitDate": "2023-02-01 09:07:31 -0800",
  "engineRevision": "800594f1f4a6674010a6f1603c07a919b4d7ebd7",   
  "dartSdkVersion": "2.19.1",
  "devToolsVersion": "2.20.1",
  "flutterRoot": "C:\\tools\\flutter"
}
```

I want set in a varaible `engineRevision` value using a `.bat` file

I tried with `findstr` but I know how.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Comment: please update the question with your `findstr` attempt and the (wrong) output generated by your code